# Sin conexión al router en Ubuntu (máquina virtual)

Tags: ubuntu

instalé en una máquina virtual Ubuntu server y al descargarme un programa, me dí cuenta de que no tenía conexión a Internet, hice un ping a mi router y no había conexión. Mi archivo interfaces está bien configurado y además lo intenté modificando el archivo resolv.conf pero nada. También miré la configuración de vmware y está todo bien, lo tengo en modo puente. Estos son los archivos:

interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto ens33
iface ens33 inet static
address 192.168.1.141
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
```

resolv.conf:

```
nameserver 1.1.1.1
search example.org
```

/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yam1:

```
network:
          ethernets:
               ens33:
                     addresses:
                     -  192.168.1.141/24
                     gateway4: 192.168.1.1
                     nameservers:
                           addresses:
                           - 1.1.1.1
                           search:
                           - example.org
                     optional: true
          version: 2
```

¿Alguien me puede ayudar?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta quitando el modo puente y dejandolo en modo NAT, utiliza un servicio DNS.

Comment: No funciona....